# Issue with injecting JS code into WebView

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm working with android's WebView and I have this piece of code that turns the background orange.

```
@Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    wv.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                            document.body.style.background = 'orange'; 
                    "})()");
                }
```

When ever the page I want load's, the background is orange.

But when I try to hide a button that is on the page I am viewing..

```
@Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    wv.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                    "var input = document.getElementById('submit');" +
                    "input.style.display= 'none';" +  
                    "})()");
                }
```

it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that onPageFinished is called when the page has completed loading from the network, not necessarily the same time as the DOM is ready. Do you see any JavaScript errors in logcat?

You may have more luck if you register the JS function in an onload event listener.